# How to find out if a standard fiori App can be extended

Tags: sap-fiori

I am a newbie for Standard Fiori Application Extension.

I want to know how to find out if a particular Standard Fiori Application can be extended?

To which extend that particular Standard Fiori Application can be extended?

Regards,

Sayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fiori Documentation gives you *extension points* in the "Implementation Information" section.

E.g. in [Create Sales Orders](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps(%27F0018%27)/W13):
[image: Fiori apps library documentation showing extension points]

Comment: I am refering "Manage Banks" App ( https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps('F1574')/S6OP ). Here only BSP Application name is shown,Extension Points in Views and Controller is not mentioned.

Then how to find out till which extend it can be customized ?

Regards,

Sayed

Comment: This is a transctional app. According to the book "Fiori implementation and Development" from Anil Bavarju the transactional apps are modification-free which means any update from SAP side will not be impacted.  Follow then the approach: modify the SAP Business Layer first, then Gateway layer and then the UI Layer. (not all of them have to be extended, it depends on your needs)  Best regards,